# Will this question about Easter eggs be closed as off topic?

Tags: support, scope, historical-lock

I wish to know some of the Easter egg facts of Facebook at this site. I have noticed a similar question [Hidden features of Google Search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/753/hidden-features-of-Google-search). Below the question I found a note that

> Please note that this question exists because it has a high level of
>   significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for
>   this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask
>   similar questions here.

So if I ask a question about Facebook Easter eggs will it be closed? I would like to ask the community before posting such a question on the site.

Comment: For heaven's sake, learn how to use proper capitalization and punctuation.  _Every_ single post of yours has been edited, cleaning up cruft.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This type of question is now considered not constructive as it is basically asking for a list of answers each of which is equally "correct".

If any existing questions are still open, then depending on the question it might either be closed or locked as an historical artefact.

If you ask a new question of this type then it is highly likely that it will be closed.